# How to invoke a java method based on a subclass type?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to dispatch objects to separate method according to their subclass.

For instance, consider those 2 objects

```
class A extends I {}
class B extends I {}
```

and the method

```
void dispatch(I i) {}
```

in `dispatch()`, I'd like to invoke a method according to the type of `i`. Hence if `i` is actually of type A, the `handlerA(A a)` method will be called. If it's of type B, `handlerB(B b)` will be called, and so on ... I tried with method overloading but I guess it doesn't work this way

what is the best way to achieve this ? I'd like to avoid using if/else statement ...

Thanks in advance,

edit: I can't modify any of those classes.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

In short, have `I` declare an `accept(Visitor<T> ...)` method, and have `Visitor` expose `onA(A ...)`, `onB(B ...)`, etc. methods.  Your implementations of the `I` interface will call the appropriate method on the passed in `Visitor<T>`.

Its probably not worth it (due to boilerplate) if you only have 2 concrete classes, but somewhere around 3 or 4 it starts being worth it - if just to avoid duplicated if-else constructs.

Answer (score 3):

So in `I` you declare the `handler()` method, and implement it appropriately (i.e. differently) in both `A` and `B`.

This is Polymorphism :)

Comment: This assumes that `handler()` makes sense to have on `A` and `B`.  If that's the case, your answer is 100% correct.

Comment: Kevin: You're right, it does. But only kind of. I still think the OP is missing the underlying concept of Polymorphism, and even if my exact suggestion isn't suitable, I think some scheme of a function/property in `I` is the way to go.

Comment: if handler() is in I, and both A and B implement I, but it doesn't make sense to have handler() on both, I think there are **probably** other problems.

Comment: sorry I should have specified that I can't change any of thoses classes.

Comment: pinpinlelapin: Yes ... that changes things. If you can't change A or B or I, you'll need to do type-checking. Which is really quite, well, not ideal, to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Since your edit, I assume you cannot edit A,B and I;
this leads to bad news:

You can inherit from `A` say `C` in this class (C) you may call `super.dispatch()` so you can reach the base class `A.dispatch()`.

- But due to design (unconsidered inheritance) you cannot reach `I`. This would be like calling super.super which is not allowed
- In Java, you can't call super().super().. Childs have acces to their parents, but not to their grandparents.

So you're a victim of bad design.
EDIT: fixed typo

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way you can do this is to use type checking.  I understand that this is not supposed to be encouraged, but...

```
void dispatch(I i)
{
   if(i instanceof A)
   {
      handlerA();
   } 
   else 
   {
      handlerB();
   }
}
```

But seriously, if you can avoid it at all, do not write code like this.  If you can't modify them, could you by any chance extend A and B, add in a different handler() method for both and and use these new subclasses instead of A and B?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Adapter Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AdapterPattern) is more applicable than the Visitor Pattern in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use Scala, you can write

```
i match {
  case a: A => handlerA(a) 
  case b: B => handlerB(b)
  case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown i: " + i.toString)
}
```